# Matplotlib Basemap color plot with contourf and pcolormesh throwing errors

Tags: python, matplotlib, compiler-errors, map-projections, matplotlib-basemap

My program reads data giving coordinates and inclination values from a .txt file, plugs it into an exponential regression to get the corresponding error values for inclination, and then graphs error by coordinates on a map of the Earth. I've succeeded at mapping points with varying sizes using Matplotlib Basemap, but my goal is to create a color plot. I've tried contourf and pcolormesh but keep getting errors, and I suspect that my problem lies in the dimensions of the arrays I'm using for graphing. latValues and longValues are my coordinate arrays, and errorValues represents intensity. When I tweak my code using contourf, the two errors I've been getting are "IndexError: too many indices" and "MaskError: Mask and data not compatible." With pcolormesh I get "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack." I've tried studying the documentation and employing solutions to other people's similar problems, but nothing has improved. I appreciate your help!

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import fabs, pow, e


'''put latitude and I value into an array'''

filename = raw_input('Enter filename: ')
txt = open(filename)

length = 1      #length of current line
curLine = 0     #entire line
curLat = 0      #latitude of current line
curLong = 0     #longitude
curI = 0        #inclination (dip angle)
valuesArray = []  #stores lat, long, and I values

while length != 0:   #while current line has data (i.e., isn't empty)
    curLine = txt.readline()
    length = len(curLine)
    if length != 0:
        curLat = float(curLine.split()[0])   #get first non-whitespace chunk and change type to float
        curLong = float(curLine.split()[1])  #get second non-whitespace chunk and change type to float
        curI = fabs(float(curLine.split()[-1]))    #get last non-whitespace chunk and change type to float. abs val
        valuesArray.append([curLat, curLong, curI])

'''append error values to valuesArray after calculate error by plugging in I values into equation'''

curError = 0    #current

def regression(inclin):  #this is the regression equation based off the table in the magnetometer manual used to calculate error values
    curError = 1.505690874240565 * pow(10, -13) * pow(e, (0.348649 * inclin))
    return curError

counter = 0
while counter < len(valuesArray):
    valuesArray[counter].append(regression(valuesArray[counter][2])) #append error value to valuesArray
    counter = counter + 1

latValues = []     #list of latitude values
longValues = []    #list of longitude values
inclinValues = []  #list of inclination values
errorValues = []   #list of error values
counter2 = 0

while counter2 < len(valuesArray):    #create arrays for each value (lat, long, inclin, and error)
    latValues.append(valuesArray[counter2][0])
    longValues.append(valuesArray[counter2][1])
    inclinValues.append(valuesArray[counter2][2])
    errorValues.append(valuesArray[counter2][3])
    counter2 = counter2 + 1

#change lists to arrays to numpy arrays if needed
##latValues = np.asarray(latValues)
##longValues = np.asarray(longValues)
##inclinValues = np.asarray(inclinValues)
##errorValues = np.asarray(errorValues)
##latValues = np.frombuffer(latValues)
##longValues = np.frombuffer(longValues)
##inclinValues = np.frombuffer(inclinValues)
##errorValues = np.frombuffer(errorValues)    

'''set up south polar stereographic basemap and try to graph'''

m = Basemap(projection='spstere', boundinglat=-35, lon_0=90, resolution='l') #boundinglat determines how graph is zoomed in
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='brown', lake_color='blue')

x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid(longValues, latValues)
x, y = m(x2d, y2d)
##plt.pcolormesh(x, y, errorValues, cmap=plt.cm.jet)  #if i want to try to get pcolormesh to work
m.contour(x, y, errorValues, levels = range(-180, 360, 30), colors = 'orange')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81.,20.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,20.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color = 'blue')

plt.title("South Polar Stereographic Projection")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It would be helpful (for us and you) to verify the size and shape of the arrays etc. in use `numpy.shape` on `x`,`y`, `errorValues` and anything else would be useful.  Just use any data you have (arbitrary number of points), it's the relative differences that will help.  That'll help us see which bits might be causing trouble.